# Please, why is "Popcorn" not replaced by "Coke" in my code?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, replace

I am working on a program to get the total of items ordered in a store, for instance. I created a dictionary called menu for the available items, but if the item ordered in the list of orders is not among the key. Same of my dictionary "menu", that item should be replaced with Coke.

My intention is to convert the items to their prices, which are the corresponding values in the dictionary and do the necessary total afterwards.

But it seems, like in the example, Popcorn is not giving way.

```
a = ["Pizza", "Cheeseburger", "Water", "Popcorn"]
menu = {"Nachos":6,"Pizza":6,"Cheeseburger":10,"Water":4,"Coke":5}
for i in a:
   if not i in menu:
      i = "Coke"
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` variable just represent the current item from the iterable, to replace the value in the array, you may use its index, `enumerate` gives tuple `(index, element)`

```
order = ["Pizza", "Cheeseburger", "Water", "Popcorn"]
menu = {"Nachos": 6, "Pizza": 6, "Cheeseburger": 10, "Water": 4, "Coke": 5}
for idx, item in enumerate(order):
    if item not in menu:
        order[idx] = "Coke"
print(order) # ['Pizza', 'Cheeseburger', 'Water', 'Coke']
```

But you'll be looking for the prices just next, you can do it in the same shot

```
total = 0
for item in order:
    total += menu.get(item, menu["Coke"]) # if item not present, get price of Coke
print(total)
```

Comment: Notice the usage of the `enumerate` built-in to access both the index and item at the same time. This is preferred to something like a range function because it's clearer and explicit.

Comment: a =input().split()
     #a = ["Pizza", "Cheeseburger", "Water", "Popcorn"]
       menu =  {"Nachos":6.00,"Pizza":6.00,"Cheeseburger":10,"Water":4.00,"Coke":5.00}
     total = 0
     for item in a:
        total += menu.get(item, menu["Coke"])  
    print(1.07*total) #adding 7% tax
This code works for the only two open test cases, but failed all the three other hidden test cases. Can't figure out what is wrong....

Comment: @mko77 I absolutly don't know, I answer your problem, but don't know about your excercise

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your for-loop is you that you loop through the *value* of each element in a. Then inside your if-statement you replace the *value*, and not the original entry in `a`. Instead you have to reference the entry in `a` using it's index.

Try this

```
a=["Pizza", "Cheeseburger", "Water", "Popcorn"]
menu = {"Nachos":6,"Pizza":6,"Cheeseburger":10,"Water":4,"Coke":5}
for i in range(len(a)):
   if not a[i] in menu:
      a[i]="Coke"
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not replace Popcorn with Coke because you are not manipulating list `a`.

`i` in your code is copy of objects in list `a`. `i` does not refer to the objects in `a`. So, updating value of `i` does not update the object in the list `a`.

You need to manipulate objects in list `a`. Check code below:

```
a = ["Pizza", "Cheeseburger", "Water", "Popcorn"]
menu = {"Nachos":6,"Pizza":6,"Cheeseburger":10,"Water":4,"Coke":5}
for n, i in enumerate(a):
   if not i in menu:
      a[n] = "Coke"
print(a)
```

Result:

```
['Pizza', 'Cheeseburger', 'Water', 'Coke']
```

Answer (score 1):

when you iterate over your list `a` using the `for` loop you are assigning  at each iteration step to the variable `i` a consecutive value from `a`, so if you change the value of the variable `i` you are not  changing the value from `a`, to change the  values from `a` you have to access them by index:

```
a = ["Pizza", "Cheeseburger", "Water", "Popcorn"]
menu = {"Nachos":6,"Pizza":6,"Cheeseburger":10,"Water":4,"Coke":5}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if  a[i] not in menu:
        a[i] = "Coke"
print(a)
```

output:

```
['Pizza', 'Cheeseburger', 'Water', 'Coke']
```

or you could use a list comprehension:

```
a = [e if e in menu else 'Coke' for e in a]
# ['Pizza', 'Cheeseburger', 'Water', 'Coke']
```

to compute the total price you could use:

```
sum(map(menu.get, a))
# 25
```

Comment: I just can't thank you enough, @kederrac. You cleared it all for me

Comment: I was able to adapt it to solve the two test problems, but it is failing some hidden test problems. Cannot figure out where the bug is.

Comment: well, I suggest to accept one answer, and then you can open another question :) with the details of the new issue :)

Comment: please guide me, don't know where to accept the answer, I merely up voted them

Comment: @mko77 you can read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work